# Add attribute inside HTML elements of a React component

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a React component ***without the capability of changing its source code***. This component, lets say `<Demo />` renders a lot of `<a> ...<a/>` HTML elements. Is it possible to add an attribute inside those elements programmatically and how?

Comment: Well, you could always put a wrapper around it and hack the DOM yourself in a `useLayoutEffect`, or if it's an npm package, [`patch-package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a wrapper where you create a reference for the wrapper tag. with that you could query for specific elements and change its attributes accordingly:

```
const wrapperComponent = props => {
  const myRef = React.createRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current.querySelector("a").innerText = "got changed!"
  }, [myRef])

  return (
    <div ref={myRef}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why `myRef.current` equals null?

Comment: My guess is that you added the `ref` to the `Component` directly instead of a wrapping tag, and if that's the case is not going to work.